# ¿Cómo puedo saber que radio button está seleccionado utilizando Jquery?

Tags: jquery, radiobutton

Tengo dos `radio buttons` y quiero mostrar el valor en pantalla. ¿Cómo puede obtener el valor con JQuery?

Puedo obtener todos los elementos así:

```
$("form :radio")
```

¿Cómo puedo saber cual es el seleccionado?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para obtener el valor del elemento `radioName` seleccionado de un formulario con id `myForm`:

```
$('input[name=radioName]:checked', '#myForm').val()
```

EJEMPLO:

```js
 $('#myForm input').on('change', function() {
     alert($('input[name=radioName]:checked', '#myForm').val()); 
  });
```

```html
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <form id="myForm">
    <input type="radio" name="radioName" value="1" /> 1 <br />
    <input type="radio" name="radioName" value="2" /> 2 <br />
    <input type="radio" name="radioName" value="3" /> 3 <br />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

En el ejemplo, tuve que aperturar el jQuery y me funcionó

```
$(document).ready(function(){...aquí va el código...});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#form input').on('change',function(){
  alert($('input[name=tipoHelpTools]:checked','#form').val());
 }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">  
<label>
<input type="radio" name="tipoHelpTools" id="tipoHelpTools" value="Compra" checked="">
Compra
</label>
<label>
<input type="radio" name="tipoHelpTools" id="tipoHelpTools" value="Mantenimineto">
Mantenimiento
</label>
 </form>
```